# Flatlist rows overlap the elements of other rows on element transform

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, android-tv

I have a flatlist which contains some list of images (Inside touchableopacity) and on each image focus i'm scaling the image to 1.3. Here the next row is always overlapping the first row image when scaled.

```
         <FlatList
          style={[styles.flatlist, styles.outline]}
          decelerationRate="fast"
          data={this.props.posters}
          contentContainerStyle={{
            flexDirection: 'column',
            paddingTop: perfectSize(50),
            paddingLeft: perfectSize(40),
            paddingRight: perfectSize(40),
            paddingBottom: perfectSize(50),
          }}
          numColumns={7}
          horizontal={false}
          ref={ref => (this.scroller = ref)}              
          scrollEventThrottle={400}
          renderItem={({item, index}) => (
            <Poster
              key={index + 1}
              defaultFocus={this.state.posterNum}
              onFocus={this.handleAccessible}
              handleClick={this._onPosterClick}
              onLayout={this.handleScroller}
              data={item}
              index={index + 1}
            />
          )}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        />
```

Poster component code is below

```
   <TouchableHighlight
    ref={itemRef => {
      this.refers[`${each.id}_${i}_pos`] = itemRef;
    }}        
    accessible={true}
    hasTVPreferredFocus={defaultFocus}
    style={[styles.poster_box_small]}
    onFocus={() => this._onPosterFocus(`${each.id}_${i}`, i)}
    onPress={() => this._onPosterClick(each, i)}
    onBlur={() => this._onPosterBlur(`${each.id}_${i}`)}>
    <LinearGradient
      colors={['#BF55DE', '#080808', '#00BDE6']}
      start={{x: 0, y: 1}}
      end={{x: 1, y: 0}}
      ref={itemRef => (this.refers[`${each.id}_${i}_lg`] = itemRef)}>
      {/* Poster :: Background Image */}
      <ImageBackground
        style={styles.poster_banner}
        resizeMode="cover"
        source={{uri: each.image}}>
        {/* Bottom Left Flag :: Collected/UnCollected score */}
        {this.getScoreUI(each)}
        {/* Center Dots :: Show only during file load */}
        <View style={styles.poster_center_view}>
          <Text style={styles.poster_center_circle}>. . .</Text>
        </View>
        {/* Top Right Flag :: TV Collection */}
        {this.getTVFlag(each)}
      </ImageBackground>
    </LinearGradient>
  </TouchableHighlight>
```

onFocus and onBlur i'm just swapping the class

```
// Poster Focus :: scale it and show border
_onPosterFocus = (key, i) => {
  this.props.onFocus && this.props.onFocus(i);
  this.refers[`${key}_pos`].setNativeProps({
    style: styles.poster_box_large,
  });
  this.refers[`${key}_lg`].setNativeProps({
    style: styles.poster_gradient_large,
  });
};

// Poster Blur :: Remove scaling and remove border
_onPosterBlur = key => {
  this.refers[`${key}_pos`].setNativeProps({style: styles.poster_box_small});
  this.refers[`${key}_lg`].setNativeProps({
    style: styles.poster_gradient_small,
  });
};
```

Css of poster component

```
poster_gradient_large: {
    padding: perfectSize(3),
},
poster_gradient_small: {
    padding: perfectSize(0),
},
poster_box_small: {
    width: perfectSize(235),
    height: perfectSize(334),
    margin: perfectSize(6),
    transform: null,
    zIndex: -1,
},
poster_box_large: {
    width: perfectSize(235),
    height: perfectSize(334),
    margin: perfectSize(6),
    transform: [{scale: (1.1, 1.3)}],
    zIndex: 1,
},
poster_banner: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(51,50,59,1)',
    zIndex: 1,
},
```

Problem is like this, the next row in flatlist is overlapping the scaled image but the top rows are not overlapping. This is happening for all images.

[image]

Comment: you should use elevation on android. in the psoter_box_large style, try to add elevation: 2 below zIndex: 1

Comment: I tried, it is still same. If you see the Poster is scaled correctly but the next row is overlapping. In case if all four sides of the poster is overlapped `zIndex` or `elevation` should work.

Comment: [https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28751](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28751)